# Autowired Beans (Nested) in a Request Controller are Null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

I have migrated our project from Spring (5.2.x) to Spring 6 with Hibernate 5.6. I am using JDK17 and our application server is Tomee 9.1.1.

Now when I access one of the RestAPI, the beans(autowired) within the autowired beans are null due to which I am hitting on NPE. I see few of the beans are proxied using Spring CGLIB

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.hp.nieto.services.system.NietoSystemSettingsService.isOTMMShowActiveSessionsEnforced()" 
because "this.nietoSystemSettingsService" is null at com.hp.nieto.business.NietoConfigurationBusinessLogic.isOTMMShowActiveSessionsEnforced(NietoConfigurationBusinessLogic.java:1328) 
~[nieto-business-logic-24.1.0.jar:?]at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
~[?:?]at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) 
~[?:?]at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) 
~[?:?]at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:352) [spring-aop-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:713) [spring-aop-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
```

Following is how I have added my RestAPI

Interface

```
@Controller
@Api(value = "Collections", description = "the Collections API")
public interface CollectionsApi
```

```
@Controller
public class CollectionsApiController implements CollectionsApi {

@Autowired
    NietoOTMMSessionBussinesLogic nietoOTMMSessionBussinesLogic;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<PublishCollectionRestResponse> publishCollection(
            @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authorizationHeader,
            @PathVariable("id") String collectionId,
            @Valid @RequestBody PublishCollectionRestRequest publishRequest,
            HttpServletRequest servletRequest, Locale locale) {

        PublishCollectionRestResponse publishedCollection = new PublishCollectionRestResponse();

        try {
            NietoUser loggedUser = nietoOTMMSessionBussinesLogic.getNietoUser(authorizationHeader);
}
```

Note: I am able to call getNietoUser here as I am able to see that NietoOTMMSessionBusinessLogic is autowired properly.

```
@Service
public class NietoOTMMSessionBussinesLogic {

@Autowired
    private NietoConfigurationBusinessLogic nietoConfigurationBusinessLogic;

public NietoUser getNietoUser(String authorizationHeader) throws NietoException {

 if (nietoConfigurationBusinessLogic.isOTMMShowActiveSessionsEnforced()) {
                UserSessionsResponse userSessionsResponse = client.getCurrentUserAllActiveSession();
                user.setUserSessionsResponse(userSessionsResponse);
            }
   ...

}
```

Note: I am able to trigger nietoConfigurationBusinessLogic.isOTMMShowActiveSessionsEnforced()) call as well

```
@Service
public class NietoConfigurationBusinessLogic {
 @Autowired
    NietoSystemSettingsService nietoSystemSettingsService;
}

public boolean isOTMMShowActiveSessionsEnforced() {
        return nietoSystemSettingsService.isOTMMShowActiveSessionsEnforced();
 }

}
```

Here nietoSystemSettingsService is null to call on the method. Hence getting the NPE exception here

Application Context file configuration is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hp.nieto.*" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean           class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <!-- Session Factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="com.hp.nieto.config.providers.jpa.NietoLocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files"></prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class"> -->
                <!-- com.hp.nieto.config.providers.jpa.SpringSessionContext -->
                <!-- </prop> -->
                <!-- Connection pool -->
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>
                <!-- Turning on the second level cache in general -->
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <!-- Turning on the query cache regions. The query and timestamp cache
                    regions will be created and used -->
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <!-- Hibernate will create separate cache regions for Hibernate caching,
                    instead of trying to reuse cache regions defined elsewhere in the application -->
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.jcache.internal.JCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jakarta.cache.provider">org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jakarta.cache.uri">/assetview-cache-config.xml</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.allow_load_outside_transaction">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.hp.nieto.model.*" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.hp.nieto.config.providers.jpa.NietoDataSource">
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
                          transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"       class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on"/>
</beans>
```

Previous version of my project used to work without any issues.

I had tried adding @PostConstruct for autowiring the bean in CollectionsApiController and NietoConfigurationBusinessLogic but It didn't help in my situation. Not sure what is wrong with the configuration. It would be great if anyone can share their thought on this issue.

@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if(applicationContext !=null) {
        applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
    }
}
```

I had similar autowiring NPE issues while invoking any service using it's constructor.

Comment: It cannot be `null` else your application wouldn't even start. So there is something else going on that isn't visible from what you posted here. From your config ditch `context:annotation-config` that is already implied by the component scan, and remove the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which is also implied. I doubt that this is the actual code that is being used. The method either isn't `public` or it is marked `final` (I suspect) instead of what you posted here.

Comment: Thank you Denium for the reply. Only few beans that are proxied via Spring CGLib is null. I had posted the actual code here and the method is public and not final and I have manually injecting the beans through ApplicationContext explicitly. Even this didn't help
Exception:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
~[?:?]at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:352) [spring-aop-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:713) [spring-aop-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]

Comment: Again a field cannot be `null` as the application wouldn't even start. Hence something in your code must prevent a method to be proxied and is actually invoked on the proxy. Which generally is the case with non public methods, final methods or for some reason double proxying.

Comment: Ok, method is public and not final. So can help me with more ideas with double proxying. In which scenarios I can expect double proxying.

Comment: Well figure out what is leading to a proxy of `NietoConfigurationBusinessLogic` and why it doesn't proxy the method. As you have some excessive configuration (mentioned in my first comment) you probably have something else as well.

Comment: You've entered a holy-war area for spring developers.    IMHO (and my comment will typically invoke the holy-war) .. is move to constructor injection.  see: https://dev.to/felixcoutinho/you-should-stop-using-spring-autowired-p8i      I know "we'll fix it later, we promise, I just need to get through this , this time"     Everyone tells you how annotations save time.  But it all gets lost the first time the magic does not work.  (as you are encountering right now).  let the holy war begin.